# Start/join Google Hangout without Google+ account

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

Is it possible to start and/or join a Google Hangout on Android without also having a Google+ account?

Answer (score 1):

From the [support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3094760?hl=en)

> Do users need a Google plus account to use Hangouts?
>
> No, but some features—using apps in video calls, sharing photos, and using circles to control who can reach you and how—require a Google+ profile. See the following for more information: [Hangout video call features available with or without a Google+ profile](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6054672) and   [Hangouts Chat vs. Google Talk](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4564211)

For Google app users the [additional information](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6054672) states:

> Although Google+ provides a superior experience, it is not required for Hangouts for Google Apps to work.

In the Android gapps package it appears to require a Google account, but only Google plus to send pictures.

Comment: I am specifically asking about Hangouts on Android, not the Web interface.

Comment: Sorry, added now, had to run at the time, slipped my mind @ale.